# SQL Server 2016- send automatic email after store proceedure executes

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

Is it possible to have a stored procedure send an email after it executes successfully. I have an alert account set up but dont know how to create a trigger after the procedure completes. very new here

Answer (score 5):

There are a number of ways to do this.

1. Edit your SP to include a call to [sp_send_dbmail](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-send-dbmail-transact-sql) upon successful completion of whatever logic you have.  I would suggest nesting this into some [TRY/CATCH](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/try-catch-transact-sql) logic.  This will be the most direct route and will allow the notification(s) to occur regardless how the SP is called.
2. Call your SP via a SQL Agent Job, and configure it to [send a notification to an operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/agent/notify-an-operator-of-job-status) upon conclusion of the job (e.g. completion, success, or failure).
3. Call your SP via a SQL Agent Job and include a secondary step calling sp_send_dbmail.  This is helpful if there are more than one party or email distribution list you want to notify as the built in notification methods within a SQL Agent job are rather limited.

Comment: How would I edit the current procedure to include this? When i right click edit it I do not see an option to add anything its only to change current parameters.

Comment: @Joe `Right-Click` -> `Script Stored Procedure As...` -> `Alter To` -> `New Query Window` Based on the question, I'm going to assume you are new to TSQL, so in this case you'll want to look up some examples and test things out before you edit your production code.  There are some [examples of how to use sp_send_dbmail](http://bit.ly/2rOb3hE) at the bottom of the routine's definition page.  Here's an article on how to [call one SP from another](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/callingexecuting-sql-stored-procedure-from-another-stored-procedure1).